# Sharepoint and reporting services, how to reuse a report in another environment?

Tags: reporting-services, reports

I see some link on a SharePoint 2010 portal. When I click on the link below I need to wait for 30 seconds and then I see some report generated and is showing in the reportviewer. It shows all items from the sharepoint list "Catalog". The results are grouped by column "Expertise".

[http://myCompany.com/_layouts/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/Rapporten/Catalogus1.rdl&Source=http%3A%2F%2FmyCompany%2Ecorp%2Enibra%2Enl%2FRapporten%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1&DefaultItemOpen=1](http://myCompany.com/_layouts/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv%3aRelativeReportUrl=/Rapporten/Catalogus1.rdl&Source=http%3A%2F%2FmyCompany%2Ecorp%2Enibra%2Enl%2FRapporten%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1&DefaultItemOpen=1)

How can I reuse this report in another enveronment? In the other environment I use SharePoint 2013.

Do I need to go to the sql server and open a new browser window and enter localhost/Reports. Here I will find propably the report Catalogus.rdl. I need to download it and upload it in my other environment. What about the SharePoint RSViewerPage.aspx. Is it Always available or do I need to activate some feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Report Builder to open the report for edit and save it to a file share. You should have Report Builder available on the ribbon in the Reports library in SharePoint.
Then upload the report to SharePoint 2013 using Report Builder from that site. There will be two different versions of Report Builder for the two versions of SharePoint. Unfortunately I don't have an instance of SharePoint 2010 to try this out on, but it should be fairly straight forward. Check the data source when you upload to make sure it is configured correctly.

You may be able to just open the report from SP2010 and save it to 2013, but I don't know for sure.

Report Library/Report Viewer will be available for you if you have SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Edition